# android webview integrate google ima

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have been trying to integrating my application with webview, the sample of the google provied html5 sdk that was worked in the web but not in android webview asset. And the error is

> "02-28 12:33:00.279: I/chromium(15835): [INFO:CONSOLE(124)] "Uncaught
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined", source:
>   file:///android_asset/index2.html (124)"

i'm using eclipse to develop my app.
Thanks.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>IMA HTML5 Simple Demo</title>
    <!--link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///android_asset/style.css"-->
  <style>
    #mainContainer {
      position: relative;
      width: 640px;
      height: 360px;
 }

 #content, #adContainer {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   width: 640px;
   height: 360px;
 }

 #contentElement {
   width: 640px;
   height: 360px;
   overflow: hidden;
 }

 #playButton {
   margin-top:10px;
   vertical-align: top;
   width: 350px;
   height: 60px;
   padding: 0;
   font-size: 22px;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
   background: #2c3e50;
   border: 0;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #22303f;
   cursor: pointer;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px #22303f;
   box-shadow: inset 0 -2px #22303f;
 }
  </style>
  
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="mainContainer">
      <div id="content">
        <video id="contentElement">
          <source src="http://rmcdn.2mdn.net/Demo/vast_inspector/android.mp4"></source>
          <source src="http://rmcdn.2mdn.net/Demo/vast_inspector/android.webm"></source>
        </video>
      </div>
      <div id="adContainer"></div>
    </div>
    <button id="playButton">Play</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//imasdk.googleapis.com/js/sdkloader/ima3.js"></script>
    <!--script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/ads.js"></script-->
 <script>
  // Copyright 2013 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
// You may study, modify, and use this example for any purpose.
// Note that this example is provided "as is", WITHOUT WARRANTY
// of any kind either expressed or implied.

var adsManager;
var adsLoader;
var adDisplayContainer;
var intervalTimer;
var playButton;
var videoContent;

function init() {
  videoContent = document.getElementById('contentElement');
  playButton = document.getElementById('playButton');
  playButton.addEventListener('click', playAds);
  setUpIMA();
}

function setUpIMA() {
  // Create the ad display container.
  createAdDisplayContainer();
  // Create ads loader.
  adsLoader = new google.ima.AdsLoader(adDisplayContainer);
  // Listen and respond to ads loaded and error events.
  adsLoader.addEventListener(
      google.ima.AdsManagerLoadedEvent.Type.ADS_MANAGER_LOADED,
      onAdsManagerLoaded,
      false);
  adsLoader.addEventListener(
      google.ima.AdErrorEvent.Type.AD_ERROR,
      onAdError,
      false);

  // Request video ads.
  var adsRequest = new google.ima.AdsRequest();
  adsRequest.adTagUrl = 'https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?' +
      'sz=640x480&iu=/124319096/external/single_ad_samples&ciu_szs=300x250&' +
      'impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=vast&unviewed_position_start=1&' +
      'cust_params=deployment%3Ddevsite%26sample_ct%3Dlinear&correlator=';

  // Specify the linear and nonlinear slot sizes. This helps the SDK to
  // select the correct creative if multiple are returned.
  adsRequest.linearAdSlotWidth = 640;
  adsRequest.linearAdSlotHeight = 400;

  adsRequest.nonLinearAdSlotWidth = 640;
  adsRequest.nonLinearAdSlotHeight = 150;

  adsLoader.requestAds(adsRequest);
}


function createAdDisplayContainer() {
  // We assume the adContainer is the DOM id of the element that will house
  // the ads.
  adDisplayContainer = new google.ima.AdDisplayContainer(
      document.getElementById('adContainer'), videoContent);
}

function playAds() {
  // Initialize the container. Must be done via a user action on mobile devices.
  videoContent.load();
  adDisplayContainer.initialize();

  try {
    // Initialize the ads manager. Ad rules playlist will start at this time.
    adsManager.init(640, 360, google.ima.ViewMode.NORMAL);
    // Call play to start showing the ad. Single video and overlay ads will
    // start at this time; the call will be ignored for ad rules.
    adsManager.start();
  } catch (adError) {
    // An error may be thrown if there was a problem with the VAST response.
    videoContent.play();
  }
}

function onAdsManagerLoaded(adsManagerLoadedEvent) {
  // Get the ads manager.
  var adsRenderingSettings = new google.ima.AdsRenderingSettings();
  adsRenderingSettings.restoreCustomPlaybackStateOnAdBreakComplete = true;
  // videoContent should be set to the content video element.
  adsManager = adsManagerLoadedEvent.getAdsManager(
      videoContent, adsRenderingSettings);

  // Add listeners to the required events.
  adsManager.addEventListener(
      google.ima.AdErrorEvent.Type.AD_ERROR,
      onAdError);
  adsManager.addEventListener(
      google.ima.AdEvent.Type.CONTENT_PAUSE_REQUESTED,
      onContentPauseRequested);
  adsManager.addEventListener(
      google.ima.AdEvent.Type.CONTENT_RESUME_REQUESTED,
      onContentResumeRequested);
  adsManager.addEventListener(
      google.ima.AdEvent.Type.ALL_ADS_COMPLETED,
      onAdEvent);

  // Listen to any additional events, if necessary.
  adsManager.addEventListener(
      google.ima.AdEvent.Type.LOADED,
      onAdEvent);
  adsManager.addEventListener(
      google.ima.AdEvent.Type.STARTED,
      onAdEvent);
  adsManager.addEventListener(
      google.ima.AdEvent.Type.COMPLETE,
      onAdEvent);
}

function onAdEvent(adEvent) {
  // Retrieve the ad from the event. Some events (e.g. ALL_ADS_COMPLETED)
  // don't have ad object associated.
  var ad = adEvent.getAd();
  switch (adEvent.type) {
    case google.ima.AdEvent.Type.LOADED:
      // This is the first event sent for an ad - it is possible to
      // determine whether the ad is a video ad or an overlay.
      if (!ad.isLinear()) {
        // Position AdDisplayContainer correctly for overlay.
        // Use ad.width and ad.height.
        videoContent.play();
      }
      break;
    case google.ima.AdEvent.Type.STARTED:
      // This event indicates the ad has started - the video player
      // can adjust the UI, for example display a pause button and
      // remaining time.
      if (ad.isLinear()) {
        // For a linear ad, a timer can be started to poll for
        // the remaining time.
        intervalTimer = setInterval(
            function() {
              var remainingTime = adsManager.getRemainingTime();
            },
            300); // every 300ms
      }
      break;
    case google.ima.AdEvent.Type.COMPLETE:
      // This event indicates the ad has finished - the video player
      // can perform appropriate UI actions, such as removing the timer for
      // remaining time detection.
      if (ad.isLinear()) {
        clearInterval(intervalTimer);
      }
      break;
  }
}

function onAdError(adErrorEvent) {
  // Handle the error logging.
  console.log(adErrorEvent.getError());
  adsManager.destroy();
}

function onContentPauseRequested() {
  videoContent.pause();
  // This function is where you should setup UI for showing ads (e.g.
  // display ad timer countdown, disable seeking etc.)
  // setupUIForAds();
}

function onContentResumeRequested() {
  videoContent.play();
  // This function is where you should ensure that your UI is ready
  // to play content. It is the responsibility of the Publisher to
  // implement this function when necessary.
  // setupUIForContent();

}

// Wire UI element references and UI event listeners.
init();

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For web, the IMA SDK only supports desktop web (in a full-fledged browser) or the mobile web (Chrome on Android, or Safari on iOS). Implementations built inside a WebView object might throw error, since a WebView is not a full-fledged browser and might not have all the functionalities required by IMA to work.

For compatibility, check [this page](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/compatibility).